# VPN tunneling through another VPN

Tags: vpn, networkmanager, pptp

in windows you can simply create two pptp connections and after connecting to one of them, easily connect to the other one while maintaining the first.

Is there any way to do this (cli or gui) in linux? 
I also found this [resource](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220861/how-do-i-create-a-vpn-over-another-vpn), but found it rather unhelpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok , i found a solution , i made the vpn connections with pptpsetup tool , and after editing /etc/ppp/peers/* , i connected to the first vpn through `pon` command or `pppd call` and routing my traffic through this connection (ppp0) (route add default dev ppp0) after that i connected to the second vpn (pppd call) and routed again , problem solved!

i also tried connecting to one vpn by NetworkManager and the second with pon (and vise-versa) but it didn't work.

guide for pptpsetup : [PPPTP setup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PPTP_VPN_client_setup_with_pptpclient)

Answer (score 0):

NetworkManager AFAIK still doesn't support multiple VPN services at once. You can do magic with setting those up manually but this feature is simply not yet available with current versions of the software.